# Using GLPK in parallel_for loop

Tags: c++, concurrency, glpk

I want to run the LP solver in GLPK in a parallel_for loop. The problems are all independent of each other so there shouldn't be any interference.

Here is an example code that fails, this is essentially the example code from the glpk wikibook but wrapped in a parallel_for loop. Any help will be appreciated

```
//#include <stdio.h>            /* C input/output                       */
//#include <stdlib.h>           /* C standard library                   */
#include <iostream>
#include <glpk.h>             /* GNU GLPK linear/mixed integer solver */
#include <ppl.h>

using namespace concurrency;
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    parallel_for(0, 10, [](int i){
        /* declare variables */
        glp_prob *lp;
    int *ia = new int[4];
    int *ja = new int[4];
    double *ar = new double[4];
    double z, x1, x2;


    /* create problem */
    lp = glp_create_prob();
    glp_set_prob_name(lp, "minimax");
    glp_set_obj_dir(lp, GLP_MAX);


    /* fill problem */
    glp_add_rows(lp, 2);
    //glp_set_row_name(lp, 1, "p");
    glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 1, GLP_UP, 0.0, 1.0);
    //glp_set_row_name(lp, 2, "q");
    glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 2, GLP_UP, 0.0, 2.0);


    glp_add_cols(lp, 2);
    //glp_set_col_name(lp, 1, "x1");
    glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 1, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
    glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 1, 0.6);
    //glp_set_col_name(lp, 2, "x2");
    glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 2, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
    glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 2, 0.5);


    ia[1] = 1, ja[1] = 1, ar[1] = 1.0; /* a[1,1] = 1 */
    ia[2] = 1, ja[2] = 2, ar[2] = 2.0; /* a[1,2] = 2 */
    ia[3] = 2, ja[3] = 1, ar[3] = 3.0; /* a[2,1] = 3 */
    ia[4] = 2, ja[4] = 2, ar[4] = 1.0; /* a[2,2] = 1 */
    glp_load_matrix(lp, 4, ia, ja, ar);



    /* solve problem */
    glp_simplex(lp, NULL);
    /* recover and display results */
    z = glp_get_obj_val(lp);
    x1 = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 1);
    x2 = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 2);
    printf("z = %g; x1 = %g; x2 = %g\n", z, x1, x2);
    /* housekeeping */
    glp_delete_prob(lp);
    glp_free_env();
});
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: I get access violations:

eg: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC44FB1D57 (glpk_4_52.dll) in OOT.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

It's un predictable though, the compiler doesn't always break at the same spot.

Comment: Use a debugger.  Check whether any of your pointer variables end up being NULL.

Comment: Nothing seems to be getting NULLed, it's very unpredictable. For example if I make the number of iterations lower, sometimes the code goes through with no problem. Sometimes after the first couple etc... And the error doesn't always happen at the same place. It just seems like the threads are interfering with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. The issue is with the GLPK source code, there are a couple of routines that are not reenterable causing some big issues. This is documented here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Using_the_GLPK_callable_library . There is also a fix in place but it requires rebuilding it. Note that this only works with version 4.50 of GLPK and older, newer versions have a slightly different layout.

While Ben was completely correct, making this change to the library solves all issues and lets you free the environment inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `glp_free_env` from inside each thread, while the library is still actively doing work in other threads.  That won't work well -- you're yanking the rug out from under threads working hard..

Instead call it only after all threads completed computation (join them).  For this simple example, you can probably skip the cleanup step altogether.

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved most of my problem. By now it's made me realize that glpk doesn't even seem to run in multiple cores. My Quad-Core stays at a steady 25% when going through the iterations.

Do you think if I create an object and do the optimization process in there and create separate objects for each iteration it would fix this issue? Or is the problem with the glpk dll?